# How do I use Group By with order function in R

Tags: r, sorting, group-by, data.table

I have a dataframe with 120000 records and 19 variables, 2 of which are state and MonthlyIncome.

I have to create a new dataset with top 10(in terms of monthly income) customers from each state.

I tried a lot of options including data.table and dplyr and base but there is always something missing.

**data.table :**

```
 x <- customer_any_360[,order(-dense_rank(MonthlyIncome))[1:10], by = state]
```

--- example I tried

Could someone please help, am still new to R and really struggling with this problem. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide some example data.  May be `customer_any_360[dense_rank(-MonthlyIncome), .SD[1:10], by =state]`  Replacing `.SD` by `.I` and extracting the index would be more faster though.  I am guessing you are mixing `dplyr` and `data.table` functions.  A `data.table option would be `frank(-MonthlyIncome, ties.method='dense')`

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(state) %>% top_n(10, MonthlyIncome)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use `rank` functions, one option is `frank` from `data.table` where you can specify the option in `ties.method`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(customer_any_360)[, .SD[frank(-MonthlyIncome, 
               ties.method='dense') %in% 1:10], by = state]
```

Or even just `order` is sufficient

```
setDT(customer_any_360)[order(-MonthlyIncome), .SD[1:10], by = state]
```

---

Using `dplyr`, there are mutliple options, `dense_rank`, `min_rank`, `top_n` depending on what you wanted.  Also, for filtering, `slice` or `filter` can be used.

```
library(dplyr)
customer_any_360 %>%
           group_by(state) %>%
           slice(dense_rank(-MonthlyIncome)[1:10])
```

---

Or using `sqldf`

```
 library(sqldf)
 sqldf('select * from customer_any_360 i
          where rowid in 
          (select rowid from customer_any_360 
           where state = i.state 
           order by MonthlyIncome desc 
           limit 10)
  order by i.state, i.MonthlyIncome desc')
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
indx <- with(customer_any_360, ave(-MonthlyIncome, state,
       FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method='first')) %in% 1:10)
customer_any_360[indx,]
```

---

EDIT: The `frank` option was edited with suggestions from @Arun

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
customer_any_360 <- data.frame(cust=1:120000, state= sample(state.abb,
  120000, replace=TRUE), MonthlyIncome= sample(1000:6500, 120000, 
     replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice. But, you're selecting the first 10. I don't think using `dense rank` or `order` makes a difference for ties/without ties..? You might have to move `frank` to `j` and subset `.SD[rank %in% 1:10]` I think for what you want to do for data with ties.

Comment: Thanks!! Few questions please - a) what does the .SD[] does in data.table?    b)in the base R method using ave - use of %ini% and when I tried the method the table that I got had the same values that other methods derived but those weren't ordered.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @RanjanPandey `.SD` is `Subset of Datatable` Regarding `ave`, the code, gives the logical TRUE/FALSE in the same order as in the dataset.  So, when we use that for subsetting, it will remove the FALSE rows.  To order, it you can use `order` later.

Answer (score 3):

Use ddply from plyr package:

```
data(iris)
ddply(iris, "Species", function(x) head(x[order(x$Sepal.Length, decreasing = TRUE) , ], 2))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
2          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
3          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
4          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
5          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
6          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
```

Comment: It worked YAYY!! Thanks. just one question could you please explain how does function recognizes that the argument to be passed is the data - iris.

Comment: function takes x as argument, where x can be anything. Only constraint is that x should have a x$Sepal.Length vector. And ddply works in a way that the first argument (here it is iris), will be passed to whatever function you give as third argument (after doing the grouping specified by the second argument). So iris will be passed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track by seeking the answer in the amazing `data.table` package.  Here I just made up some data for states 1 through 50, and drew incomes from a normal distribution N(50000, 20000^2).

**with edits based on** comments from @Arun and request for all columns from OP (using the .SD hidden variable):

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.table(state = 1:50, 
                     monthlyIncome = round(rnorm(120000, 50000, 20000)),
                     anothervar = 1:120000)
selecteddata <- mydata[order(-monthlyIncome), head(.SD, 10), by = state]

# just to verify
selecteddata <- selecteddata[order(state, -monthlyIncome)]
mydata <- mydata[order(-monthlyIncome)]
identical(selecteddata[1:10], mydata[state==1][1:10])  # state 1
identical(selecteddata[11:20], mydata[state==2][1:10]) # state 2
```

Comment: Nice answer ! But it would be much more efficient if you moved the ordering to the `i` argument and do it just once totally, instead of calling it once for each group.

Comment: Thanks @Ken Benoit and Arun. But like Arun said it is only returning the 2 columns - how do I get all the columns from the data set?

Comment: Thanks @Arun, I moved the ordering to the `i` argument as you suggested. @Ranjan Pandey with the new `.SD` syntax you should get all columns now. (I added a made up one just to demonstrate.)